# Search posts by Tag

Tags: search, tags

I'd like my search forms to only display results organized by tag.

I know you can add `&tag=TAGNAME` to the end of a search results URL, but how do I integrate it into a form so that my site only searches for posts containing tags equal to whatever was entered in the search box?

I have two searches on the page, so ideally I'd like to be able to add it via HTML into the forms themselves as opposed to anywhere else, but any answer is fine :)

thanks

Comment: There are a number of very similar questions. Look to the right under "Related".

Answer (score 2):

You can hook inside the result, so that you change the query and search about the tags.
The result is than a loop with all posts to this tag.

You can relized this inside the template, there are is the output for search or write a small plugin, that hook inside the query and change the query, if it your search; perhaps with your url param. For the plugin use the hook `pre_get_posts`.

see:

- [Query and Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters)
- [Hook in Query Example](http://wpengineer.com/2176/exclude-posts-and-pages-in-wordpress-search/)
- [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)